# Relation between Digital frequency counter and temperature

Tags: frequency, temperature, counter

This is a homework question, I can normally solve the problems on freqeuncy counter but I never did with temperature related frequency counter problems.

A digital frequency counter has these properties.

```
Display 10 Digits. 
Timebase-oscillator:(Ftbu=10MHz) 
Mode:Frequency-measurement 
High-precision-input-signal(Finp)=200MHz +- 0.0002Hz 
Measurement time: 1sec
```

1. Room-temperature:40 centigrade. The display shows the value 200001000. What is the actual frequency of the time base oscillator.

2.Which accuracy has the local time-base-oscillator?

3.The room-temperature changes to 0 degree Centigrade. Now the display shows the value 200002000. Which temperatur-drift has the local time-base-unit. Derive the temperatur-coefficent of time base unit. Which value will be visible on the display at a temperature of 20 Centigrade.

Comment: Can you write an equation for the reading as a function of the actual timebase frequency? Where are you running into trouble?

Comment: This is the question. there is no more informations.

Comment: I can see what the question is. Where are *you* running into problems?

Comment: So it's assumed that the one second gate pulse comes from the 10 MHz oscillator.  (Does that help?)  (I must admit I was a bit confused when I first read the question.) (And that's some room that goes from 40 C to 0.)

Comment: actually i don't know what to do with this questions. I kindly request you to help me,if you could.

Comment: Can you try and describe how the counter works?  Maybe then we can see your problem.  If I just tell you the answer is 42, does that help you at all?  (besides getting a better grade on one HW.)

Comment: *Hint:* If the timebase oscillator was totally accurate what **should** a highly accurate input frequency of 200MHz +/- 0.0002Hz actually read on the 10 digit display? **But it doesn't**, it reads slightly higher, the question tells you how much higher- what is this error as a % of the input frequency? To produce this the local timebase must be running **slower** by the same %.